# angular material table load data after sorting

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material table to display data. Currently, i want to load angular material table sorted from status. I have 3 status - complete, pending & fail. I want fail record to show last and complete and pending records should display first.

I used below sorting function to do it, but its not working.

```
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results['InvoiceHeaders']);
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    switch (property) {
      case 'status': return item.element.status;
      default: return item[property];

      //     default: return item[property];
    }
  };
  this.dataSource.sort = this.viewsort;
```

Can u help me to do these type of sample.

Thanks

Comment: I supouse you can create an object like `statusList={complete:0,pending:1,fail:2}` and make `return statusList[item.element.status]`, but I can not test it

Comment: where i create object ??

Comment: is a variable in your component.ts

Comment: i found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to create a field 'statusWeight' and assign a sortable numeric value to the 'status' column, and then use the default material sorting on that arbitary column.

- complete to have value 1
- pending to have value 2
- fail to have value 3

relevant **HTML**:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="statusWeight" matSortDirection='asc' class="mat-elevation-z8">
....
</table>
```

working [stackblitz available here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gykpre?file=app%2Ftable-sorting-example.html)